Make new objects smaller by default
I am working on a smaller milimeter scale in blender. If I add new objects, then they are extremly big. Why are they not scaled to the unit you work with? Is there a way to make them initially smaller?
Currently I always have to resize them to make them fit my scene, because they are bigger than the whole scene.

Did you try that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70318/how-can-i-make-the-default-size-of-new-objects-1-x-1 ? It changes the default units, meaning your object have the same size but 1m becomes 1mm.

A default file (Header > File > Defaults > Save Startup File) saved with these settings should set you up for working in millimetres:
:

I've tried it. If I add a cube then it is still way oversized.

Ok, I understand now thx to GPT. You mean that we need to go to File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File. I had to restart blender and now it works.

Hi, @Black Sorry.. I'll make that clearer. The adjustment works straight away for me.. but all the tools do remember the parameters they were last used with, so if you created a 2m cube before adjusting the settings, then 'Add Cube' wil add a 2000mm cube, until you type in 2mm., on next use
